# how to get jenkins serenity test case reports in json format or is there an API to do so?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, maven, jenkins, serenity-bdd

so, whenever jenkins runs my code and generates report, is there an api or any way to get all those results. my final aim is to collect all those reports and create custom UI, so that whenever jenkins generates result. the UI should automatically fetch results from json output and show it on my customised UI. (my backend code is in Ruby on rails - so similar gem or API would be helpful)

Answer (score 1):

All the Serenity test outcomes are generated in JSON format in the target/site/serenity directory.

Comment: thanks for reply, is it possible to write a test runner for serenity where i should be able to get all json files combined to single file with perticular name.? i did this in cucumber.  `@CucumberOptions(
 features="features",
 plugin={"json:target/cucumber.json"}
 )` since serenity generates various details of a report, i need a combination of all those json files in a single file . so that i can use it in my application.

Comment: @Sachinsrinivasan You should be able to concatenate the results utiizing the post-build step in Jenkins- either with a groovy script or another application.